# How to make color border in ComplexHeatmap package

Tags: r, heatmap

In ComplexHeatmap package I can't find a way to draw a border around the heatmap. I have illustrated the question in the attached image. Can anyone please help me to do so? Thanks in advance!

Example code:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(circlize)

set.seed(123)
mat = matrix(rnorm(80, 2), 8, 10)
mat = rbind(mat, matrix(rnorm(40, -2), 4, 10))
rownames(mat) = paste0("R", 1:12)
colnames(mat) = paste0("C", 1:10)
#plot
Heatmap(mat, cluster_rows = F, cluster_columns = F, show_heatmap_legend = FALSE)
```

Example picture with border.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the email reply from the author.

```
mat = matrix(rnorm(100), 10)

Heatmap(mat, name  = "foo")

decorate_heatmap_body("foo", {

    grid.rect(gp = gpar(fill = "transparent", col = "black", lwd = 2))

})
```

In `decorate_heatmap_body()`, the first argument is the "name" of the heatmap

which you need to define in `Heatmap()`.